# https secure on AWS ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, https

I have an app running on aws ec2 (all is fine) but I want to use https do I need a certificate? And do the input traffics ports have to be set to a speciffic number - the app is supported by node and express

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For HTTPS, yes you need a certificate. You can use [AWS Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) to obtain a certificate.

Since you are using a NodeJS application, you can use a Nginx proxy to terminate the HTTPS.

For HTTPS default port is 443.

You can refer [this documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-nodejs.html) to configure HTTPS termination.